# Efficacy and Purpose of AntiForgery.Validate in AJAX calls

Tags: ajax, vb.net, security, asp.net-mvc-4, antiforgerytoken

The MVC4 SPA template has a `ValidateHttpAntiForgeryTokenAttribute` class with a `ValidateRequestHeader` function that parses out 2 halves of a `RequestVerificationToken` header constructed by the client when it assembles the data for an AJAX call. The client AJAX code gets its value from a field on the form that combines a form token and a cookie token. I feel like combining these into a single value loses sight of the purpose of an AntiForgery token; they were separate for a reason. Do we gain any security by using anti-forgery tokens in this way?

Server .vbhtml code (Razor-based):

```
Public Function GetAntiForgeryToken() As String
    Dim cookieToken As String = String.Empty
    Dim formToken As String = String.Empty

    AntiForgery.GetTokens(Nothing, cookieToken, formToken)
    Return cookieToken & ":" & formToken
End Function
```

...

```
@If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
    @<input id="antiForgeryToken" type="hidden" value="@GetAntiForgeryToken()" />
End If
```

Client AJAX code:

```
function ajaxRequest(type, url, data, dataType) { // Ajax helper
    var options = {
        dataType: dataType || "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        cache: false,
        type: type,
        data: data ? ko.toJSON(data) : null
    };
    var antiForgeryToken = $("#antiForgeryToken").val();
    if (antiForgeryToken) {
        options.headers = {
            'RequestVerificationToken': antiForgeryToken
        }
    }
    return $.ajax(url, options);
}
```

Server validation code:

```
Private Sub ValidateRequestHeader(request As HttpRequestMessage)
    Dim cookieToken As String = String.Empty
    Dim formToken As String = String.Empty

    Dim tokenHeaders As IEnumerable(Of String) = Nothing
    If request.Headers.TryGetValues("RequestVerificationToken", tokenHeaders) Then
        Dim tokenValue As String = tokenHeaders.FirstOrDefault()
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenValue) Then
            Dim tokens As String() = tokenValue.Split(":"c)
            If tokens.Length = 2 Then
                cookieToken = tokens(0).Trim()
                formToken = tokens(1).Trim()
            End If
        End If
    End If

    AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken)
End Sub
```

What prevents a client from picking any arbitrary pair of cookieToken and formToken that was used in the past, and submitting them together in an AJAX call to get it to go through? Isn't that what anti-forgery functions are supposed to prevent? Is this just a lot of stupid overhead that doesn't improve security, or is there a piece of it that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What prevents a client from picking any arbitrary pair of cookieToken and formToken that was used in the past, and submitting them together in an AJAX call to get it to go through? Isn't that what anti-forgery functions are supposed to prevent? Is this just a lot of stupid overhead that doesn't improve security, or is there a piece of it that I'm missing?

The anti-forgery token is not designed to prevent a [Replay Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack). This is where old values are reused to create another request where the aim is to fool the target machine into accepting a valid instruction from the past.

The anti-forgery token is designed to prevent [Cross Site Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) attacks.

A simple example is as follows:

- You're logged into `bank.com` on one tab.
- You get an email to view a funny video by clicking on a link that redirects you to 
  `evil.com`
- The web page on `evil.com` contains a hidden form that is submited by JavaScript to `bank.com/make_money_transfer`

As you are logged into `bank.com` and your cookies are sent by the browser, `bank.com` thinks that you made the request and initiates the money transfer without your knowledge, because from the server's point of view, all is well.

The token is designed to prevent this by having something included in the request payload that cannot be auto submitted by a domain that is not the current domain. Due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) another domain cannot access the token value and therefore cannot send a legitimate request via a hidden form, or by any other means. The token is unique per log in session so the attacker could not get a valid combination of token and cookie which can be sent to the server.

Looking at the source code for [TokenValidator.cs](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/a19eb63170f9#src/System.Web.WebPages/Helpers/AntiXsrf/TokenValidator.cs) (albeit C# instead of VB.NET) we can see that the `ValidateTokens` method checks that the username encoded in the token matches the one of the current HTTP request:

```
if (!String.Equals(fieldToken.Username, currentUsername, (useCaseSensitiveUsernameComparison) ? StringComparison.Ordinal : StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
     throw HttpAntiForgeryException.CreateUsernameMismatchException(fieldToken.Username, currentUsername);
}
```

This is what will stop an attacker grabbing an old version of the form field value and submitting that in their CSRF attack - their encoded username will not match the logged in user of their victim.

Comment: But the cookie and token values in the template code *are* both stored *on the form*! Doesn't that defeat the security of the cookie token?

Comment: Sorry - Slightly misunderstood your original question! Anyway, I've updated it with the answer.

Comment: Just one problem with the notion that the username is what prevents that: the template code is passing "Nothing" for the IIdentity parameter, which, unless I'm reading the code wrong, causes currentUsername to remain empty.

Comment: The only `Nothing` I see is in `AntiForgery.GetTokens` for the `oldCookieToken` parameter? The username isn't passed, it's worked out from `HttpContext`.

Comment: Ah, right. Then the one question remaining in my mind is, why maintain a cookie token (aka session token?) and a form token (aka field token?) separately when they're both going on the form anyway. Why not just use the fieldToken/formToken?

Comment: Because the Microsoft Anti Forgery library was initially designed to work with multi page web applications - here it is using the same underlying framework for a single page application. Hence the reason for leaving the value in the page rather than passing it about in a cookie.